# small screen in virtualbox installed OSs

Tags: debian, virtualbox

have installed two virtual OSs. The host OS is debian. Two virtual OSs are win XP and debian ( without graphical environment) . I have install guest additions too. The win XP one is displayed in fullscreen mode but the debian one isn't. Is it related to it is in text mode ? How can I bring it to fullscreen mode?

I use virtualbox.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As your Debian box does not have the GUI installed, I suggest to use SSH to manage the box. Please disregard the virtual display from VirtualBox for daily use as it is way less powerful than using SSH (no copy&paste, less than easy file transfer, etc.) when using a Linux OS as the host.

If you really need to work on a `tty` on one of the VTs in full screen you could just let it scale up with low quality, use KMS and some kernel boot parameters to set a bigger screen size for which you need VirtualBox 4.2 or up ([read here](http://www.phoronix.com/scan.php?page=news_item&px=MTAxOTk)).

Comment: Combine SSH with `screen` to keep your terminal sessions on the guest open even if you close your local window.

Comment: My virtualbox is 4.2.0 . So it seems using SSH is the best solution in this case. Thank you.

Comment: When going to SSH, it's perphaps a good thing do run VirtualBox headless, then.